# Javascript elements buggy overtop of iFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm using the jQuery UI framework to create a draggable panel. It works fine, but when I drag it over top of an embedded iframe on the page it becomes buggy and stops moving. I thought it could just be the plugin, but it happens with all of my dynamically created elements that move overtop of the iframe.

Does anyone know what is going wrong or how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to kind of hide the iframe when you drag/resize the panel. This can be done by placing a hidden transparent div right over the iframe (of the same size), and showing it up only when the drag/resize event is triggered. So keep on toggling as soon as the drag/resize start and stop events are triggered.

Comment: Hmm. Not sure that helped... I already had a semi-transparent grid style `div` overlaying the frame, yet it's still glitching out. I also use the jQuery.Ruler plugin which tracks the cursor position on the screen, and when the coordinates box moves across the frame with the cursor it also gets glitchy.

Comment: Here is almost literally my exact code - just a few changes: http://jsfiddle.net/uEGZP/

Comment: Added `iframeFix: true` and removed `$.cookie` stuff, it's working fine now - http://cssdeck.com/labs/2q17bb4t